# Tkinter Script Autostart

Tags: python-3, tkinter

I have a problem with loading the Tkinter script at every reboot of the Raspberry. The script is executable and starts from a .desktop file. No problem with it when the Raspbian OS is booted (I guess Stretch, Raspberry Pi 3 B+).
What I have already tried:

1. Moving .desktop file in /home/pi/.config/autostart or /etc/xdg/autostart;
2. Adding a line @python3 /home/pi/Documents/stesk_tkinter_backup2.py (my script; I also tried to add "sudo") in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart;
3. rc.local;
4. systemd (the service was working but couldn't start the script; the action was repeated every 10 sec).

Maybe I have to add some code into the script?
Here is the beginning of the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
from PIL import ImageTk, Image #pip3 install Pillow
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import io
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from statistics import mean
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import threading
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess
import os
import shutil
import psutil
from pyowm import OWM
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import time
import cv2
import board
import busio
import digitalio
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

mcp1 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x20)
mcp2 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x21)

mcp1_a0 = mcp1.get_pin(0)
mcp1_a1 = mcp1.get_pin(1)
mcp1_a2 = mcp1.get_pin(2)
mcp1_a3 = mcp1.get_pin(3)
mcp1_a4 = mcp1.get_pin(4)
mcp1_a5 = mcp1.get_pin(5)
mcp1_a6 = mcp1.get_pin(6)
mcp1_a7 = mcp1.get_pin(7)
mcp1_b0 = mcp1.get_pin(8)
mcp1_b1 = mcp1.get_pin(9)
mcp1_b2 = mcp1.get_pin(10)
mcp1_b3 = mcp1.get_pin(11)
mcp1_b4 = mcp1.get_pin(12)
mcp1_b5 = mcp1.get_pin(13)
mcp1_b6 = mcp1.get_pin(14)
mcp1_b7 = mcp1.get_pin(15)

mcp2_a0 = mcp2.get_pin(0)
mcp2_a1 = mcp2.get_pin(1)
mcp2_a2 = mcp2.get_pin(2)
mcp2_a3 = mcp2.get_pin(3)
mcp2_a4 = mcp2.get_pin(4)
mcp2_a5 = mcp2.get_pin(5)
mcp2_a6 = mcp2.get_pin(6)
mcp2_a7 = mcp2.get_pin(7)
mcp2_b0 = mcp2.get_pin(8)
mcp2_b1 = mcp2.get_pin(9)
mcp2_b2 = mcp2.get_pin(10)
mcp2_b3 = mcp2.get_pin(11)
mcp2_b4 = mcp2.get_pin(12)
mcp2_b5 = mcp2.get_pin(13)
mcp2_b6 = mcp2.get_pin(14)
mcp2_b7 = mcp2.get_pin(15)

mcp1_a0.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a1.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a2.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a3.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a4.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a5.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a6.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_a7.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b0.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b1.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b2.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b3.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b4.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b5.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b6.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp1_b7.switch_to_output(value=True)

mcp2_a0.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a1.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a2.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a3.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a4.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a5.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a6.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_a7.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b0.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b1.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b2.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b3.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b4.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b5.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b6.switch_to_output(value=True)
mcp2_b7.switch_to_output(value=True)

from picamera import PiCamera

try:
    camera = PiCamera()
except:
    print("PiCamera is not connected/damaged")

kit = ServoKit(channels=16)

GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
##GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
##GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
##GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)

mcp3 = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(0, 0))
mcp4 = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(0, 1))

#PIR
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
pir = MotionSensor(22)

from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
```

etc...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **systemd** is the way to start programs on boot up. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/119995/edit) your question and add the Unit file you have tried.

Comment: questions about starting a python script at boot have been asked many times

Comment: Please have a look a [systemd-startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:79866+[systemd-startup])